# Listen to event component of sibling in extjs 6?

Tags: events, extjs, mvvm, extjs6, extjs6-classic

I'm developing an [Extjs-6](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0) application using [MVVM architecture](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/application_architecture/application_architecture.html). I have a panel(`panel_a`). `panel_a` has two panels(`panel_1`, `panel_2`). `panel_1` has a component(`component_1_1`). `component_1_1` has an event(`event_1`). I want to `panel_2` listen to `event_1` .

**How can I implement this issue**?

*Note that I'm using [MVVM architecture](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/application_architecture/application_architecture.html).*

[image]

Comment: Aren't all the panels inside the same view and view controller?

Comment: All of panels have own `view`, `viewModel` and `viewContorller`. `panel_1` and `panel_2` are in `panel_1`.

Comment: Can you provide us with some code. I'm not sure what you mean, because it seems so obvious.

Comment: *"How can I implement"* isn't a valid SO question. Show what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean by listening to component_1_1 event? can you write more details? what exactly must do panel_2?

maybe you want something like this:

**VIEW**

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.mypanel',

    requires: [
        'MyApp.view.MyPanelViewModel',
        'MyApp.view.MyPanelViewController',
        'Ext.panel.Panel',
        'Ext.form.field.TextArea'
    ],

    controller: 'mypanel',
    height: 454,
    width: 891,
    bodyPadding: 5,
    title: 'panel_a',

    layout: {
        type: 'hbox',
        align: 'stretch'
    },
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'panel',
            flex: 1,
            bodyPadding: 10,
            title: 'panel_1',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    fieldLabel: 'Component_1_1',
                    listeners: {
                        change: 'onTextfieldChange'
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            xtype: 'panel',
            flex: 1,
            reference: 'panel_2',
            itemId: 'mypanel2',
            margin: '0 0 0 5',
            layout: 'fit',
            bodyPadding: 20,
            title: 'panel_2',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'textareafield',
                    height: 138,
                    width: 359,
                    fieldLabel: ''
                }
            ]
        }
    ]

});
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyPanelViewController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
    alias: 'controller.mypanel',

    onTextfieldChange: function(field, newValue, oldValue, eOpts) {
        this.lookupReference("panel_2").down("textarea").setValue(newValue);
    }

});
```